# How to save processed data in a rails model ( get NoMethodError )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to save processed data inside my model to render it as json but i get that the method is missing so time for a stupid question.

The model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.html(html)
    @html = html
  end
end
```

The controller

```
  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        @post.html render_to_string(partial: 'post.html.erb', locals: { post: @post })
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { 
          render :show, 
          status: :created, 
          location: @post
        }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `html' for #<Post:0x0000000a5679d0>:
```

That's because in the builder i would like to output

```
json.extract! @post, :id, :content, :created_at, :updated_at, :html
```

I could probably do this in another way but now i'm curious, what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add regular getter/setter:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def html
    @html
  end

  def html=(html)
    @html = html
  end
end
```

You also probably want an instance method, because you are working with instance of `Post` (you called `Post.new` earlier.

Comment: Actually i had done that, and i missed that the error was different. 
I have to define both a set_html and html method to make it work, isn't there something standard for this in rails 4?

Comment: Thankx you can actually use `attr_accessor :html` on the model :)

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti I return my honor ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you define the method `html` on the post model, you are creating a class method, and not an instance method. You need to remove the `self` and make it a setter by adding `=`:

`class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def html=(html)
    @html = html
  end
end`